# download binary file from curl in php

Tags: php, binary, http-headers, fingerprint, php-curl

I am so confused, how download attendance data (**attlog.dat**) from fingerprint device? here's my code

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.2.240/form/Download");   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('sdate' => '2020-11-25','edate' => '2020-11-26','period' => '1','uid' => '666'));
    $file = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($file,true);
    curl_close($ch);
```

And i get the response like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK 
Server: ZK Web Server 
Pragma: no-cache 
Cache-control: no-cache 
Content-Type: application/binary 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=attlog.dat 
Connection: close
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just write into a file. `file_put_contents('attlog.dat', $file);`

Comment: With your current settings the curl call will dump the file data to stdout and return the headers into `$file`. Change `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to get only the file data. Refer to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for what the various curl options are/do, but also you should consider using a library like Guzzle to abstract away the less straightforward aspects of using curl directly.